# Setting ManagedBy for ADGroup in nested OU

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a script which takes input from a CVS file and changes attributes on an AD group. Please see the code below:

```
$file = Import-Csv "C:\1.csv"
foreach ($line in $file){
    Set-ADGroup -Identity "$($line.Name)" -description "$($line.Path)" -ManagedBy "$($line.Owner)"
}
```

The CSV file has entries like:

`Name   Project Path     Owner 
XYZ Accessions  S:\XYZ  ABC`

I keep getting the below error:

> Set-ADGroup : Cannot find an object with identity:
>   'XYZ' under: 'DC=ad,DC=xx,DC=xx,DC=xx'.

The ADgroup itself is under a nested OU:

> CN=XYZ,OU=Store Permission Groups,OU=SAN Permission
>   Groups,OU=yyy,OU=yyy,DC=ad,DC=xxx,DC=xx,DC=xx

How do I get "set-adgroup" to look under a specific nested OU "SAN Permissions Group"?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You either update your CSV to store the full DistinghuishedName of the group and use that for `-Identity`, or use `Get-ADGroup` with the `-SearchBase` parameter first to find the group and if found, use the `DistinguishedName` property from that.

Comment: @Theo How would I go about using the second method with `-searchbase`? `Get-ADGroup -Filter {name -eq $line} -SearchBase "OU=blahblahblah"` doesn't seem to work

Comment: `$group= Get-ADGroup -Filter "Name -eq '$($line.Name)'" -SearchBase "OU=blahblahblah"` should work